# Understanding pointers in C in Linux with gcc compiler

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C in linux and using GCC compiler. I have a following piece of code to understand the pointers in C.

```
int main(void)
{   
     int n;
     /*long int z;*/
     int a=1025;
     int* p;
     //int* ptr=&n;
     p=&a;
     n=sizeof(double);
     //printf("\nAddress of n is =%p",&n);
     printf("\nsize of integer is %d",n);
     printf("\nAddress of a is =%p, value of a is= %d",&a,*p);
     printf("\nAddress of a is =%p, value of a is= %d",p,*p);
     printf("\nAddress of this location is is =%p, value at this location is=    %d",(p+1),*(p+1));
}
```

OUTPUT

```
size of integer is 8
Address of a is =0x7ffd56375f90, value of a is= 1025
Address of a is =0x7ffd56375f90, value of a is= 1025
Address of this location is is =0x7ffd56375f94, value at this location is= 8
```

for the last printf statement why the value comes as 8. shouldnt it be a garbage value?

Comment: To me, 8 is about as garbage as it gets :-)

Comment: 8 is a nice, garbage value.

Comment: Here this takes the value of 'n'. If I change the value of n, *(p+1) prints the value of n.

Comment: @jafar ali no it is undefined behaviour - it can be anything. If you dereference the unallocated or uninitialized object.

Comment: The code lacks `#include <stdio.h>`. Don't assume we know the library headers - post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

my compiler is giving this one for last printf

```
Address of this location is is =0xbfc283b8, value at this location is=    -1077771340
```

it's garbage. you are trying to access data from p+1 location, we don't know what is there at p+1, if that memory is reserved for someone else you may get segmentation fault also. So I think it's undefined behaviour if you de-reference unreserved memory.

Comment: I get `value at this location is=    3472272`